# xDebug doesnt show HTML output (Mac OSX Lion)

Tags: php, macos, xdebug, zend-server-ce

I just installed xDebug, It seems to work but I just get plain text output on my pages.
How can I get the html output of xDebug like it should be?

My php.ini has html_erros ON, my machine is Mac osx lion.

zendServer;

```
Zend Data Cache | Off
Zend Debugger   | Off
```

php.ini lines;

```
; html_errors
;  Default Value: On
;  Development Value: On
;  Production value: On

; zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_local_vars=On
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
```

Phpinfo() not correct;

```
    This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Extension Manager v5.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2010, by Zend Technologies
    - with Zend Data Cache v4.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2010, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Java Bridge v3.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Utils v1.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2010, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
```

Regards,
Nicky

Comment: did you add this to php.ini zend_extension = "\path\to\php_xdebug.dll"

Comment: I added the follow lines to my php.ini (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

From their website.

> **xdebug.remote_autostart**
> Type: boolean, Default value: 0
>   Normally you need to use a specific HTTP GET/POST variable to start remote debugging (see Remote Debugging). When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try to connect to a client, even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present.

Also, make sure you *disable* Zend Debugger.  In fact, I don't remember perfectly but you might have to disable other Zend stuff like Zend Optimizer.

To disable the Zend Debugger:

1. Open the Zend Server Control Panel -> http://localhost:10081
2. Disable Zend Debugger

Or, optionally, you could do this manually:

1. `$ cd /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d`
2. `$ vim debugger.ini`
3. Add a semi-colon before this line

   - `zend_extension_manager.dir.debugger=/usr/local/zend/lib/debugger`
   - which then becomes
   - `; zend_extension_manager.dir.debugger=/usr/local/zend/lib/debugger`

Comment: Thanks for you good explanation ! I edit my post above like exactly what I have, it doesn't make any sense. See my phpinfo(); this doesnt look not good at all when I see these lines? It should be show xdebug?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. There were 2 different sections in the php.ini where I had to turn html_errors on. No very good, I had to check the phpinfo() beter to see, html_errors where still 'off' after turn just one html_error section on!